# why isn't the re.group function giving me the expected output

Tags: python, python-re, findall

```
import re

v = "aeiou"
c = "qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm"
m = re.finditer(r"(?<=[%s])([%s]{2,})[%s]" % (c, v, c), input(), flags=re.I)
for i in m:
    print(i.group())
```

The above code is an attempt to solve the [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/re-findall-re-finditer/problem) question using re.finditer but for the input

> rabcdeefgyYhFjkIoomnpOeorteeeeetmy

my output is

> eef

> Ioom

> Oeor

> eeeeet

instead of

> ee

> Ioo

> Oeo

> eeeee

I would like to know the reason why

Comment: why would you expected the output without consonant at the end when your pattern have `[%s]` at the end to match a consonant?

Comment: @adamkwm but if you replace line 4 of the code I posted with `m = re.findall(r"(?<=[%s])([%s]{2,})[%s]" % (c, v, c), input(), flags=re.I)` it works perfectly; i.e if `findall` is used. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `findall()` and `finditer()` are returning different things.

In the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) doc, for `findall()`:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

for `finditer()`:

> Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string.

In your case, when you use `findall()` with a group, the whole match is ignored, it just returns a list of vowels in group. But for `finditer()`, the whole match object is returned including the ending consonant.

You have two ways to get the result,

1. Keep the current pattern and use `i.group(1)` to get the match in group 1 instead of the whole match.
2. Use lookahead assertion for ending consonant like `(?=[%s])`, then the matched string will be only vowels.